# How to create large vectors with repeated elements fast?

Tags: r, vector, profiling, rcpp

There is a vector from which I want to make a new vector by taking its elements based on a sequence:

```
set.seed(0)

n <- 1000
ncval1 <- as.integer(n)
ncval2 <- ncval1:1L
ncval3 <- sequence(ncval2, from = 1L, by = 1L)
x <- as.double(runif(n))

y <- x[ncval3]
```

This takes roughly 2.2 miliseconds. Maybe it could be sped up by taking the property of repeated elements.

Comment: are you asking about 1. creating *that* vector faster, 2. creating any vector with repeated elements faster than 2.2 miliseconds, or something else

Comment: The question is about creating a new vector "y" out of "x" by that sequence and the length of the original vector "x" is custom. So the goal would be a generalised slution.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Rcpp`.

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
  #include <Rcpp.h>
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  Rcpp::NumericVector foo(int n) {
    // draw from standard normal
    Rcpp::NumericVector r(n);
    r = Rcpp::runif(n);
    // length of result
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      l = l + i;
    }
    // subset and concatenate
    Rcpp::NumericVector a(l);
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
        a[p] = r[j];
        p = p + 1;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
')
```

### Usage for n = 10

```
> set.seed(0)
> foo(10)
 [1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
 [8] 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
[15] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.8966972 0.2655087
[22] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.8966972
[29] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.8966972
[36] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8966972 0.2655087
[43] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
[50] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.8966972
```

### Benchmark

```
n <- 1e3
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  OP={
    set.seed(0)
    ncval1 <- as.integer(n)
    ncval2 <- ncval1:1L
    ncval3 <- sequence(ncval2, from = 1L, by = 1L)
    x <- as.double(runif(n))
    x[ncval3]
  },
  foo={set.seed(0); foo(n)}, 
  check='identical'
)

$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   OP 2.109090 2.199845 3.119882 2.294714 4.213308 7.297789   100  a 
  foo 1.055756 1.190470 1.983916 1.318557 2.741124 6.850159   100   b
```

According to median, `foo()` takes only 57% of the time.

### Update

For a given vector `x` this simplifies to:

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code='
  #include <Rcpp.h>
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  Rcpp::NumericVector foo2(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
    // length of vector
    int n = x.size();
    // length of result
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      l = l + i;
    }
    // subset and concatenate
    Rcpp::NumericVector a(l);
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
        a[p] = x[j];
        p = p + 1;
      }
    }
    return a;
  }
')
```

**Usage**

```
> set.seed(0)
> x <- runif(10)
> foo2(x)
 [1] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897
 [8] 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.6291140 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
[15] 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.6607978 0.8966972 0.2655087
[22] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.9446753 0.8966972
[29] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8983897 0.8966972
[36] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819 0.8966972 0.2655087
[43] 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534
[50] 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.8966972 0.2655087 0.8966972
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How to modify this Rccp code, so that it can work with a custom vector that is given to the function? Like: foo(x, n).

Comment: @matehorvath Please see updated answer.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Also, while using Rccp, is it the fastest method by the for loops or can it be further optimised?

Comment: @matehorvath I believe not, C++ is low level and you need these loops. Even if there's some syntactic sugar from Rcpp, there probably wouldn't be significant speed improvements.